# How to write this grammar rule as C code?

Tags: c, context-free-grammar

I'm creating a parser by hand for a class in my undergrad studies, and I need to convert this first grammar rule into C code. I've gotten the last three, as shown below

```
1. Declarations -> Var_decl || Declarations Var_decl
2. Var_decl -> TYPE varList SEMI
3. varList -> var || varList COMMA var
4. var -> IDENT || IDENT RBRAK INT_LIT LBRAK

int parse_var(){
  struct token t = peek();

  if(t.tokenNum == IDENT)
  { 
    consume(IDENT);
    t = peek();

    //Check if the IDENT has [INT_LIT] after it, making it a single dimension array
    if(t.tokenNum == RBRAK) 
    {
        consume(RBRAK);
        t = peek();
        //Check if the [ has an INT_LIT] after it
        if(t.tokenNum == INT_LIT)
        {
            consume(INT_LIT);
            t = peek();
            //check for the ] 
            if(t.tokenNum == LBRAK)
            {
                consume(LBRAK);
                return 0;
            }//error handling for missing ']'
            fprintf(stderr, "Parsing error: Expected a ']' after the Integer Literal on line %d", t.lineNum);
        }//error handling for missing 'INT_LIT'
        fprintf(stderr, "Parsing error: Expected an Integer Literal after '[' on line %d", t.lineNum);
        return -1;
    }
    return 0;
}//Error handling for missing Identifier 
fprintf(stderr, "Parsing error: Expected an Identifier near text %s on line %d", t.lexeme, t.lineNum);
return -1;
}


/* Helper: consumes a comma separated list of variables
 * ex: x, y, z[5]
 * returns: -1 upon failure and 0 upon success
 */
int parse_varList()
{
    int result = parse_var();

    struct token t = peek();

    if(t.tokenNum == COMMA)
    {
        consume(COMMA);
        result = parse_varList();
    }

    return result; 
}
int parse_varDeclarations(){
  int result = parse_type();

  if(result == 0) {
    result = parse_varList();
    consume(SEMI);
   }

return result;
}
```

Any guidance would be awesome as it's been difficult finding this answer online. I think I could do something similar to how I've done the varList function, but I'm not sure if I'm even on the right track.

Comment: Yes, it is similar. The `Declarations` is simply a list of one or more `Var_decl`s, terminating when there are no more tokens.

Comment: On the whole, you're generally better off trying something (and being prepared to debug it) than hoping to find workable code with an internet search. You'll certainly learn more about programming by making your own mistakes rather than copying other people's.